# I have two datasets but different labels alignments. How do I align labels?

Tags: pytorch

I have two datasets like A dataset:{feature, label_A} and B dataset: {data, labels_B} where label_A and label_B are not aligned.

I want to write a custom dataset from these two datasets which will pass to dataloader and give outputs like feature[index], data[index], align labels (A), and index.

Comment: In the `__get_item__` function, you can use a dictionary of mappings of the labels between the 2 datasets to align one of the datasets with the other.

Comment: How do I do the task?

Comment: How do I share the demo code? It will give a clear idea. Please tell me how do I share the code?